# Push floating div right as much as necessary on hidden reveal

Tags: javascript, css

I have a set-up of nest `div`s in containers such that, when one `div` is clicked, another unfolds beneath it. There exists a third `div` floating to the right, with a `margin` to keep it relatively close to the main content on the left on large screens. A jsfiddle with my current setup can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pL72p1bq/3/).

The unfolding `div` is much wider than the "button" `div` that displays it, so I'd like for it to push the floating `div` right as long as it exists. However, once it's gone, I'd like the `div` to fall back left.

How can I achieve this, using as little javascript as possible? (Ideally, none at all.)

Comment: I think the problem is the `float` itself. The whole point of a `float` is to take it out of the normal flow. Everything else flows _around_ the floated object. So with just CSS, the floated object _won't_ react to any other content that isn't also floated.

Comment: Thanks for the jsFiddle link. It's useful to see what's going on, but without knowing specifics of why things (the css mainly) have been set up the way they are it's hard to make changes and know they'll make sense for what you're trying to implement. Others may disagree, but that's what I'm having trouble with...